Guardar condiciones en base de datos y traerlas en php
Estoy desarrollando un sistema web con lector de código de barras, estos traen condiciones según sea la marca. Por decir, una marca puede traer el peso al inicio, otra al final, alguna puede traer el código del producto entre el 3er y 6to digito etc., entonces me gustaría guardar las condiciones en una bd mysql, por decir guardar:
if(strlen == 16){ $marca = 'marca1'}

O algo por el estilo, y poderlo traer a php en una variable; aunque no sé si se pueda convertir ese string de la variable en código.

Si se podrían guardar las condiciones en la BD, pero eso es una mala idea y mala implementación del proyecto. De hecho las condicionales son precisamente para eso, para identificar las distintas situaciones y decirle al código qué hacer. Lo que puedes hacer es tener una tabla de configuración de códigos, PHP leerá esa tabla y responderá dependiendo a si la entrada coincide con algún patrón guardado. Pero se necesita un poco más de código para ver qué estás haciendo.

Te puedo dar un consejo, este tipo de condiciones lo puedes trabajar tranquilamente en un JSON con PHP, el cual lo puedes cargar al inicio de tu módulo de lectura de código de barra y tendrás a la mano, sin tomar tiempo de servidor de Base de Datos esa consulta porque imagínate la cantidad de consulta que vas a generar cada vez que leas un código, entonces te recomiendo que lo guardes en un JSON y luego en PHP lo leas como un arreglo asociativo y las condiciones las aplicas muy fácilmente y puedes hacer una interface si es necesario para el mantenimiento de ese JSON.

Puedes usar la función eval($stringCondiciones).
Debes estar consciente que eval() evalúa el string que le pases como código PHP, por lo que debes ser muy cuidadoso con quién puede colocar las cadenas que tu programa terminará evaluando (y ejecutando).
$condicion = 'if ($marca == "marca1") {echo("si es la marca buscada");}';

$marca = "marca1";
eval($condicion);


Basado en el comentario que te hice en la pregunta que realizaste, te desarrollo la respuesta aquí:
Si tienes un JSON (Ejemplo: datos.json) con las posiciones de cada parámetro, ejemplo:
{
    "NIKE": {
        "peso": "0",
        "lote": "3",
        "medida": "10"
    },
    "ADIDAS": {
        "peso": "4",
        "lote": "0",
        "medida": "7"
    },
    "PUMA": {
        "peso": "0",
        "lote": "4",
        "medida": "7"
    }
}


Así sería el PHP para tu consulta:
$json = file_get_contents('datos.json');

$datos = json_decode($json, true);

if (isset($datos['NIKE'])) {
    $datos_ext = $datos['NIKE'];

// Aqui trabajas con los datos que en tu caso es guardarlo en una DB segun 
// la subtraccion de string del codigo de barra, te puse un echo para que 
// vieras que los trae, sin embargo lo debes sustituir por el subtraer 
// (ya que el json te esta dando la posicion donde esta) y me imagino que el 
// largo de los caracteres es un estandar, sacas el valor y lo guardas en BD. 

    echo "peso: " . $datos_ext['peso'] . "<br>";
    echo "lote: " . $datos_ext['lote'] . "<br>";
    echo "medida: " . $datos_ext['medida'] . "<br>";

} else {
    // Aqui devuelves algo si no existe la marca
}


El comentario en la pregunta sobre la marca, se refiere a las distintas marcas de los distintos lectores de código de barras que podrían soportarse, no a las marcas de los artículos que podría procesar el sistema.

Yo lo haría de otra manera, explico con un ejemplo:
Supongamos que tenemos el Número 738141 y:

738 corresponden al peso -> desde el index 0 al 2
141 corresponden al código de producto -> desde el index 3 al 5

Lo que guardaría en la base de datos es un array que indica que es cada elemento, según su posición. En el ejemplo, lo que guardaría es:
// 7      3      8        1        4       1
["peso","peso","peso","codigo","codigo","codigo"]

Lo que querrá decir que la componente "peso" ocupa de la posición 0 al 2 y "codigo" del 3 al 5
Para mayor comodidad esto lo guardaría como String en formato JSON
Luego utilizaría una función, que me retorne un objeto a partir del número de código de barras y el formato, algo así:
function GetAtributos($codigo,$formato){
    $props = [];
    $codigo = strval($codigo);
    for($i=0; $i<count($formato); $i++){
        if(isset($props[$formato[$i]])){
            $props[$formato[$i]] = $props[$formato[$i]].$codigo[$i];
        }
        else{
            $props[$formato[$i]] = $codigo[$i];
        }
    }
    //retorno un objeto
    return (object)array_map(fn($a) => intval($a),$props);

    //o retorno un array asociativo, según lo mejor se acomode a tus necesidades
   //return array_map(fn($a) => intval($a),$props);

}

Luego
$array_desde_laBd = '["peso","peso","peso","codigo","codigo","codigo"]'; //esto lo tengo que traer de la base datos
$formato = json_decode($array_desde_laBd);
$atributos = GetAtributos(738141,$formato);

//Si la función GetAtributos retorna un objeto    
echo $atributos->peso;  // 738
echo $atributos->codigo; // 141

//o si retorna un array asociativo
//echo $atributos["peso"];
//echo $atributos["codigo"];


